# How to locate element on a map by xpath or css selector

Tags: html, css, xpath

I need to locate circle element in code. I have tried .//*[@id='graphicsLayer3_layer']/circle but it doesn't work.

```
<g id="graphicsLayer3_layer" data-geometry-type="polygon" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" style="display: block;">
<g/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="961" cy="-424" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="774" cy="528" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="433" cy="18" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
<g id="graphicsLayer3_layer" data-geometry-type="polygon" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" style="display: block;">
<g/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="961" cy="-424" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="774" cy="528" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
<circle fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1.3333333333333333" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="433" cy="18" r="8" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"/>
```

Comment: We'd almost certainly have to see the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css selector to locate all three circles is `#graphicsLayer3_layer circle`.

Comment: @NatalyaGlushko if this works and answers your question, you may mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the voting buttons

Comment: what if the id is dynamic and changes how can I locate it?

Comment: ids shouldn't really change. If there's only one `g` element on the page you can use `g circle`. If you want to select all circles on the page just use `circle`. You need to have something constant to select them with...

Comment: @NatalyaGlushko If you have multiple `g` elements with circles in them, add `class="exampleClass"` to them all, and then select the circles with `.exampleClass circle`. If you have a specific example let me know and I can probably help you out.

Comment: `<g id="graphicsLayer3_layer"' <g id="graphicsLayer4_layer"' <g id="graphicsLayer5_layer"` I don't know the exact Id when locating 'circle'

Comment: @NatalyaGlushko `g[id^=graphicsLayer] circle`